# loop always returns same random integer

Tags: go

I've built a function that should return a random key from a array. When it runs it is always returning the same value.

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
        keyArray := [10]string{"key0", "key1", "key2", "key3", "key4", "key5", "key6", "key7", "key8", "key9"}

        // fmt.Println(keyArray)

        fmt.Println(keyArray[rand.Intn(len(keyArray))])
        // var key = null
    }
```

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Don't seed the random number generator inside the loop. Seeding should be done only once. It sets the random number generator into a defined state depending on the seed value. Since the time does not change so fast you will get the same random number almost every time.